# Python PyProf2CallTree Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, pstats

i'm trying to run PyProf2CallTree from inside my script with the following command on Windows:

```
os.system("python pyprof2calltree.py -i inputfile.pstats -o outputfile.kgrind")
```

And This is the error im receiving:
[image]